# Continuity of the branch function at the boundary of the subdomains

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity, boundary-value-problem

I solved this exercise, but I am insecure of myself so I would like some comment from you about the correctness, or not, of my reasoning.

Consider the set $A$ and the function $f(x, y)$ such that

$$A = \{(x, y)\in\mathbb{R}^2; x > 0, y < e^{-1/x}\}$$

$$f(x, y) = \begin{cases} 2x & (x, y) \in A \\\\ y & (x, y) \not\in A \end{cases}$$

The question is: for which points of $\partial A$ is the function continuous?

*Proceedings*

First of all I had to find the boundary of $A$. I drew it on a paper, with shot consierations about the function $e^{-1/x}$. Since I have $x > 0$, at the end the boundary is given by

$$\partial A = (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2; (x > 0, y = e^{-1/x}) \cup (x > 0, y = 0)$$

(Notice: the second set should represent the equation of the positive $x$-axis, but I don't know if that is the correct way to write it.)

Now the only way for the function to be continuous is that $2x = y$ for certain $(x, y)$.
This means

$$2x = y \rightarrow x = \frac{y}{2}$$

The only points belonging to the boundary satisfying this conditions are on the positive $x$-axis at $(x, y) = (x, y/2)$ (which are infinite).

So, how much wrong am I and where? Thank you!

Comment: This function is not defined on the boundary, therefore you could only determine its limit at any point on the boundary. Even if it was defined there, the continuity requires approaching a value in the domain from an indeterminate direction so continuity can only be checked on values internal to the domain-not on the boundary.

Comment: @WindSoul Uhm, I did not really understand... Could you elaborate a bit more please? :/

Comment: $\delta A=\{ (0,y) \} \cup \{(x, e^{-\frac 1x)}\}$

Comment: @WindSoul I don't think it's correct. The second set accept also negative $x$, as well as the first set considers also negative $y$. In any case, this is the lesser problem

Comment: A is defined with x>0. A is bounded at the left by y-axis-what first set means. What negative x are you talking about? The other boundary is determined by the second set in the union. I think there is something you didn’t communicate in your exercise because there is a conflict between continuity and boundary.

Comment: @WindSoul I have written the exercise exactly how it's written in my notes. There is that set $A$, that function $f$ and the request I wrote. Unless there is some mistake in how the exercise was written, I really did not omit anything

Comment: @WindSoul Also I don't get what you mean by "the function is not defined on the boundary". $\partial A$ does not belong to $A$, but the function is well defined for all the points $(x, y)$ which do not belong to $A$, hence which belong to $\partial A$, and it's $f(x, y ) = y$.

Comment: Alright. For some reason I took A as the domain of f. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

$$\color{red}{\delta A}=\{x= 0, y\le 0\}\cup \{x\ge 0,y=e^{-\frac 1x}\}$$
Using desmos

[image: in red is the boundary of A]

The continuity of f needs checked around $\delta A$

$$\text{Continuity around (0,y) }, y\lt 0: \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,y)}{f(x,y)}=\lim_{x\to 0^-}{y}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}{2x}=\underbrace{y}_{f(0,y)}\Rightarrow (x,y)=(0,0):\text{ f discontinuous}$$

$$\text{Continuity at }(0,0):\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}{f(x,y)}=\lim_{y\to 0}y=\lim_{x\to 0}{2x}=\lim_{x\to 0}{e^{-\frac 1x}}=0, \text{ f continuous at (0,0)}$$

$$\text{Cmotinuity around }y=e^{-\frac 1x}, x\gt 0:y=2x=e^{-\frac 1x}\Rightarrow (x,y) \notin \Bbb R^2, \text { f discontinuous}$$

$$\text{ f continuous on }\delta A \text{ at } (0,0)(\therefore)$$

Comment: Thank you!! I will read this better in a while

Comment: You’re welcome.

Comment: I don't find clear why you also calculate the limit $\lim_{x\to 0} e^{-1/x}$. My function $f(x, y)$ is defined only to be $2x$ (bisectrix) or $y$ (horizontal lines)...

Comment: Left-side=right-side limit=value of function. On the frontier $x=e^{-\frac 1x}$ : $y=2x=e^{-\frac 1x}$.

Comment: At (0,0), the approach is from either left, right, or along either boundary. The approach up along y-axis was omitted (unintentionally). The idea is that the approach is made from an indeterminate direction: any path of approach should be considered.